# Print all supported countries and sub-regions

Tags: java, libphonenumber

I want to use `libphonenumber` to print all supported countries and sub-regions.

I know I can list all supported regions using:

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
for (String s : phoneUtil.getSupportedRegions()) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

But how can I access all sub-regions? The following code will print "New York, NY"

```
String nyNumber = "+1 212-565-0000";
PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(nyNumber, "CH");
System.out.println(geoCoder.getDescriptionForNumber(numberProto, Locale.ENGLISH, "US"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: I asked the same question in libphonenumber-discuss@googlegroups.com There is no direct access through code, but original data files are available at https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/resources/geocoding